# MongoDB: operator to match arrays whose elements are all contained in a specified array

Tags: mongodb, operator

The `$all` operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements.

In my situation I need the opposite: an operator that selects the documents where the value of a field is an array *whose elements are all contained* in the specified array.

For example, consider the following collection:

```
{"name": 1, "vals": ["A", "B"]}
{"name": 2, "vals": ["D", "C"]}
{"name": 3, "vals": ["A", "D"]}
```

I want to select all the documents whose `vals` field contains values in `["A", "B", "D"]`; that is, documents 1 and 3 (not 2 because "C" is not contained in the specified array).

I cannot use `{vals: {$all: ["A", "B", "D"]}}`, nor `{vals: ["A", "B", "D"]}` as both of these operations select the documents whose `vals` field contains all the specified values, which is not what I want.

Is what I need possible?

Comment: {vals: {$in: ["A", "B", "D"]}} will select all documents. not at {vals: {$all: ["A", "B", "D"]}}.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your version of MongoDB server there are a few ways to approach this.

In MongoDB 3.6+ you can use the  [`$setIsSubset` expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) (which is `true` only when the first array given is a subset of the second) via the `$expr` operator:

```
> db.haystack.find({$expr:{$setIsSubset:["$vals",["A","B","D"]]}},{_id:0})
{
    "name": 1,
    "vals": [
        "A",
        "B"
    ]
}
{
    "name": 3,
    "vals": [
        "A",
        "D"
    ]
}
```

For earlier versions of MongoDB a similar outcome is possible (but less obvious) using double negation with the [`$elemMatch` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
> db.haystack.find({$nor:[{vals:{$elemMatch:{$nin:["A","B","D"]}}}]},{_id:0})
{
    "name": 1,
    "vals": [
        "A",
        "B"
    ]
}
{
    "name": 3,
    "vals": [
        "A",
        "D"
    ]
}
```

Roughly translated: "find all documents where it is not the case that the `vals` array includes a value other than one in the provided list".

Comment: Nice explanation of $setIsSubset & $elemMatch with respect to OP question , +1

Comment: Ahh nice trick with `$elemMatch`! I had tried a similar thing with `{$not: {vals: {$nin: ["A", "B", "D"]}}}` but it didnt' work because `$not` cannot be used like that. Fortunately I'm on MongoDB 3.6.4, so I'll use the first solution which is really straightforward.